# Create a fake webcam stream for Firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox, protractor, katalon-studio

I want to create a fake webcam stream for Firefox. At the moment I have the desired capability `media.navigator.streams.fake` but I'm not sure how to get a specific video file to play.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to fake a webcam? What is your exact usecase?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Well, at the moment I've only managed to do this in chrome. Hence I didn't share my code but for clarity I added the following for chrome to my protractor configuration... ```capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {'args': ['--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream', '--use-fake-device-for-media-stream', '--use-file-for-fake-video-capture=sample.y4m']}
  },``` @RatmirAsanov

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Firefox you can use the following code in Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver


options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.set_preference("media.navigator.streams.fake", True)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options = options)
```

Or if you are using desired capabilities with other options then it will be like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities


options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.set_preference("media.navigator.streams.fake", True)
desired = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
desired.update(options.to_capabilities())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(desired_capabilities=desired)
```

PS: You can translate it into any needed programming language.

According to your question: Firefox does not support specific video file to play inside the fake webcam -- https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1429.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks Ratmir! But how might I specify playing a particular media file?

Comment: what would you suggest? :)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be that you use User Agent in chrome and then injecting the video file:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream");
options.addArguments("--use-fake-device-for-media-stream");
options.addArguments("--use-file-for-fake-video-capture=path/to/video.y4m");
options.addArguments("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0");
webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options)
```

PS: I create the issue that Ratmir Asanov commented
[github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1429](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1429)

Comment: Hi @Darkensses I'm not sure I know what --user-agent does in this context. Could you explain? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Isabella --user-agent is a chrome flag that allows 'simulating' another browser, so  the line says that we want to simulate firefox browser. You can see this feature if you enable (manually) this option in devtools (F12) and then click on Customize and Control DevTools (the button on the left of the close devtools button) then more tools>network conditions. Uncheck 'Select automatically' from the user agent section and select your browser to simulate.

You can get other user agents string here: https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play a specific file with firefox, I think you will have to simulate a webcam on your instance (with v4l2loopback for example), and then play your file on the virtual webcam with smthing like ffmpeg.
With selenium, you will also have to update your firefox profile for allowing access to your fake webcam.